# Online tool to connect to my bank account and tell me what I spend in different categories?

Tags: online

Is there a tool that can link with my bank account and show me how much money I spend on different categories eg food, public transport, etc?

A friend told me that www.waveapps.com does this but its for small business, im looking for one for my personal finances.

I was hoping for a free tool but I could pay if necessary. I live in the UK. Mint looks like it might do this but its for USA / Canada only.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced this is completely possible without additional data.

I'm categorizing my purchases now, and I keep running into things like "was this hardware store purchase for home repair, hobby tools and supplies, cookware, ..." Ditto for department stores, ditto for cash purchases which appear only as an ATM withdrawal.

Sometimes I remember, sometimes I guess, sometimes I just give up. In the end, this budget tracking isn't critical for me so that's good enough. If you really want accuracy, though, I think you are stuck with keeping all your receipts, of taking notes, so you can resolve these gaps.

Answer (score -1):

I use Banktivity.  It's very much not free, but it automatically downloads all my bank and credit card activity and has excellent reporting options.